# validating presence of attribute fails

Tags: rspec2

In my class Foo, I have:

```
belongs_to :assessment_type
validate :assessment_type, presence: true
```

My RSpec test has:

```
  it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:assessment_type) }
```

The test fails with this error:

```
1) Foo should require assessment_type to be set
 Failure/Error: it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:assessment_type) }
   Expected errors to include "can't be blank" when assessment_type is set to nil, got errors: ["can't be blank (attribute: \"name\", value: nil)", "can't be blank (attribute: \"description\", value: nil)", "can't be blank (attribute: \"logo\", value: nil)", "can't be blank (attribute: \"url_code\", value: nil)", "can't be blank (attribute: \"starts_at\", value: nil)", "can't be blank (attribute: \"contract\", value: nil)", "can't be blank (attribute: \"organization\", value: nil)"]
```

All of the attributes listed in the errors string (name, description, ...) have the same `validate` statement as assessment_type.

Why is this failing?

Comment: Can you share your `subject`?

Comment: I'm using the default subject rather than an explicitly defined subject.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.  This line:

```
validate :assessment_type, presence: true
```

should be

```
validates :assessment_type, presence: true
```